# ESP32 Two stepper motor on different speed

Tags: c, esp32

I want to control two stepper motors at the same time but one needs to be slower (about 83% in comparison with the other stepper motor). I'm using an esp32 for programming. By my code I only can change both stepper motors speed at the same time.

```
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_spi_flash.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "errno.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "driver/mcpwm.h"

#define dir 26
#define step 25
#define dir1 21
#define step1 19


void app_main(void)   {

  printf("hello");
  gpio_reset_pin(dir);
  gpio_reset_pin(step);
  gpio_reset_pin(dir1);
  gpio_reset_pin(step1);
  
  gpio_set_direction(dir, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
  gpio_set_direction(step, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
  gpio_set_direction(dir1, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
  gpio_set_direction(step1, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);


while (1)
  { 
    vTaskDelay(1000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    //Rechts
    gpio_set_level(dir1, 1); 
    gpio_set_level(dir, 1); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++)
    {
    gpio_set_level(step1, 1);
    gpio_set_level(step, 1);
    ets_delay_us(1500);
    gpio_set_level(step1, 0);
    gpio_set_level(step, 0);
    ets_delay_us(1500);
    }
```

Comment: from the look of your `for` loop, you intended do use the loop variable `'i'` for something, but have nothing using the value `i` in your loop. If you just wanted to do what you are doing 1500 times, then that's fine.  What are the errors you encounter, compiler output, warnings, etc..? What is the command line you are using to compile the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parallel programming. So you can do two things at the same time. So if you do that by this case you can program 1 stepper motor faster then the other one. See esp32 documents for examples parallel programming on the esp32

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).